# Show that the ring $\mathbb{Z}[i]/n\mathbb{Z}[i]$ is finite.

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory

I'm pretty stuck with this problem. I hope you can help me.

Let $R=\mathbb{Z}[i] .$ Consider $n \in \mathbb{Z} \backslash\{0\}$ and the ideal $I=R n$ in $R$. Show that $a+b i \in I$ if and only if $n \mid a$ and $n \mid b .$ Show that $R / I$ is a finite ring.

---

I have already shown the first part, that n|a and n|b iff $a+b i \in I$.
But how do I show that the ring is finite?

I know that $R$ is a PID and thus that I is a principal ideal. So, $I=\{n(a+i b) \mid a, b \in \mathbb{Z}, \quad n \in \mathbb{N} /\{0\}\}$ must be generated by some element $z\in R$ ; $I=\langle z \rangle$. I think I'm supposed to use these results and that n|a and b. But I just can't seem to make any connections and where to go from here.

Comment: The answers in the duplicate show that we do not need that $I$ is a prime ideal. So we can take the proof there that $\Bbb Z[i]/I$ is finite for a nonzero ideal $I$.

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** Consider the group homomorphism $$\begin{align} \mathbb Z[i] & \to (\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z) \oplus (\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z) \\ a+bi & \mapsto (a+n\mathbb Z, b+n\mathbb Z). \end{align}$$

Comment: Is this a homomorphism? It seems like it would fail for multiplication. For example $(0,1)^2 = (0,1)$ whereas $i^2 =-1 \mapsto (-1, 0)$.

Comment: @DanielApsley You are right. But only working with the underlying additive group gives you a bijection from $\mathbb Z[i]/n\mathbb Z[i]$ to $(\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z) \oplus (\mathbb Z/n\mathbb Z)$.

Comment: @DanielApsley It is a morphism strictly in the category of (abelian) groups, not in the category of rings.

Comment: I see, thank you. I missed that you said "group".

Answer (score 1):

You need not resort to any stronger features of $\mathbb{Z}[\mathrm{i}]$ as a ring. Let us consider an arbitrary ring $(A, +, \cdot)$ whose additive subjacent group $(A, +)$ is *finitely* generated as a $\mathbb{Z}$-module. Then for any $n \in \mathbb{N}^{\times}\colon=\mathbb{N} \setminus \{0\}$ we have that $nA \leqslant_{\mathrm{b}} A$ is a *bilateral* (the English idiom would be two-sided, but I dislike it) ideal -- fact which is easy enough to ascertain -- and the quotient $A/nA$ is a *finite* ring.

To show this, let us use the abbreviation $\mathbb{Z}_r\colon=\mathbb{Z}/r\mathbb{Z}$ for any $r \in \mathbb{N}$ and let us also set $B\colon=A/nA$. Remark that $n \in \mathrm{Ann}_{\mathbb{Z}}(B)$, explicitly put $n$ is in the annihilator of the $\mathbb{Z}$-module $A/nA$. This means that this quotient abelian group can be naturally equipped with a $\mathbb{Z}_n$-module structure and it is furthermore easy to see that the lattices of $\mathbb{Z}$-submodules respectively $\mathbb{Z}_n$-modules of $B$ coincide.

Since $B$ is the quotient of a finitely generated $\mathbb{Z}$-module, it remains finitely generated over $\mathbb{Z}$ and therefore -- in light of the above observation regarding the lattices of submodules (with respect to the two distinct rings of operators) -- it is also finitely generated as a $\mathbb{Z}_n$-module. This means there exists a finite set $T \subseteq B$ such that $B$ can be expressed as a quotient (homomorphic image) of $\mathbb{Z}_n^{(T)}=\mathbb{Z}_n^T$, the free $\mathbb{Z}_n$-module on set $T$. As $\mathbb{Z}_n$ and $T$ are both finite, the free module $\mathbb{Z}_n^T$ is also finite and so therefore must also be its quotient $B$.

This general reasoning applies to your particular problem since indeed $\mathbb{Z}[\mathrm{i}]=\langle \{1, \mathrm{i}\}\rangle$ is finitely generated as a(n abelian) group.

---

**P.S.** The general argument above only establish finiteness and does little to assess that order of finiteness. In your particular case however, it is clear that the additive group $\mathbb{Z}[\mathrm{i}]$ is a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module of basis $\{1, \mathrm{i}\}$ and therefore isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z}$ via the isomorphism:
$$\begin{align}
f \colon \mathbb{Z}\times\mathbb{Z} &\to \mathbb{Z}[\mathrm{i}]\\
f(r,s)&=r+s\mathrm{i},
\end{align}$$
isomorpism which has the property that $f[n(\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z})]=n\mathbb{Z}[\mathrm{i}]$. Bearing in mind that $n(\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z})=n\mathbb{Z} \times n\mathbb{Z}$, we thus infer that $f$ induces the following morphism of additive groups:
$$\mathbb{Z}[\mathrm{i}]/n\mathbb{Z}[\mathrm{i}] \approx (\mathbb{Z} \times \mathbb{Z})/(n\mathbb{Z} \times n\mathbb{Z}) \approx (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}) \times (\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})=\mathbb{Z}_n \times \mathbb{Z}_n \quad (\mathbf{Gr}),$$
on grounds of which we can claim that $\left(\mathbb{Z}[\mathrm{i}]\colon n\mathbb{Z}[\mathrm{i}]\right)=\left|\mathbb{Z}[\mathrm{i}]/n\mathbb{Z}[\mathrm{i}]\right|=n^2$.

More generally, if ring $A$ had a free $\mathbb{Z}$-module for its subjacent additive group, then the subjacent additive group of the quotient ring $A/nA$ would also be a free $\mathbb{Z}_n$-module such that $\dim_{\mathbb{Z}}A=\dim_{\mathbb{Z}_n}A/nA$.

Answer (score 0):

Consider , the ring homomorphism $f:\mathbb{Z}[i] \to \mathbb{Z}_{n}[i] $ defined by $f(a+ib)=(a+ib)(\text{mod n})$ with kernel $n\mathbb{Z}[i]$ .

Kernel $=\{a+ib : f(a+ib)=0 \}$
$=\{a+ib : (a+ib)\equiv 0 (\text{mod n})\}$
$=\{a+ib: a\equiv 0 (\text{mod n}),b\equiv 0 (\text{mod n})\} $

$=n\mathbb{Z}[i]$

Clearly, then , $\mathbb{Z}[i]/n\mathbb{Z}[i] \cong \mathbb{Z}_{n}[i] $

Clearly, $\mathbb{Z}_{n}[i]$ has finite number of elements.

Comment: @A learner What do you mean by the syntax $\mathbb{Z}_n[\mathrm{i}]$? If by $\mathbb{Z}_n$ you understand the same object that I refer to in my answer, then how do you get a $\mathbb{Z}_n$-algebra structure whose support set would contain the complex imaginary unit $\mathrm{i}$, for the syntax you put forth to even make sense algebraically?